# Facebook unity plugin IPv6 compliant?

Tags: ipv6, facebook-unity-sdk

Apple [announced](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a) that beginning June 1, 2016, “all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking.”.

Is the Facebook Unity plugin fully IPv6 only compliant?
We are still using the facebook SDK in version 6.1 build 141217.

Cheers and thaks for the great work!

Comment: You'd have to ask Facebook, we can't look into their code. I would be surprised if it didn't support IPv6 though because Facebook has been using IPv6 for a long time

Comment: They advice you to ask here. As they are monitoring the tag. ;-)
I don't expect much problems myself, but we are bound to a quite old version of the plugin, so better be safe than sorry.

Comment: I hope they then actually provide a public answer here :)